# C#, How to run a .bat file without a popup console window

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to run a `.bat` file without a popup console window.

I'm using this code:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "file.bat";
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

With this code, the program pops up a console window for a second and disappears. How to get it so that it never shows?

Comment: And what is happening...?

Comment: a console window pops up for a second , Can I get rid of it??

Comment: Think the start info param is createnowindow on my phone atm

Comment: `Project -> Properties -> Application in Visual Studio -> Output type`.  Change from 'console' to 'windows application'.

Comment: A console window pops up because you're running a .bat file....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just add

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true;
```

Console window popup will not appear

Comment: Your answer literally showed up the same instant I pressed "Post answer".

Answer (score 7):

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

To use ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, the `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` property must be false, but it looks like you were using that setting so you should be good.

Answer (score 4):

The CreateNoWindow option must be set to true

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```